# How to write dummy ALSA compliant device driver?

Tags: linux, audio, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, alsa

I want to write dummy ALSA compliant driver as a loadable kernel module. When accessing it by aplay/arecord throught the ALSA-lib, let's say, it must behave as normal 7.1 channel audio device providing all the basic controls at least - sampling rates, number of channels, format, etc...
Underneath it will just get every channel from the audio stream and will send it through the network as UDP packet stream.
It must be capable to be loaded multiple times and ultimately it would expose as many as want audio devices under /dev. In that way we will have multiple virtual sound cards in the system.

What should be the minimal structure of such a kernel module?
Can you give me an example skeleton (at least the interfaces) to be 100% ALSA compliant?
ALSA driver examples are so poor...

Comment: You probably don't need to create a kernel module. What you want is to write an alsa plugin that will create an alsa device and put any channel on the network. you can have a look at what pulseaudio is doing or simply configure pulse audio to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I see. But I really want to have it in the kernel space in order to use it for anything else. I'm planning to control LEDs out of this driver also.

Comment: Which is something you can also do from userspace

Comment: Actually the LEDs are lasers for transmitting the audio as a back-up communication channel. So there are timing constraints and it is not suitable for the user space...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've just found what I need.
There are no better ALSA interface examples than "dummy" and "aloop" templates under sound/drivers directory in the kernel tree:

https://alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-dummy

https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-aloop

I'll need to implement the network part only.

EDIT:
Adding yet another project for a very simple but essential virtual ALSA driver:

https://alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Minivosc

EDIT 2020_09_25:
Yet another great ALSA example:

https://www.openpixelsystems.org/posts/2020-06-27-alsa-driver/

Answer (score 2):

- install `alsa-base` `alsa-util`
- `modprobe snd-dummy`
- use `alsamixer` or use `mocp`(need install moc) to conifg add dummy-audio success